# Sorting words in a text file (with parameters) and writing them into a new file with Python

Tags: python, string, list, file, sorting

I have a file.txt with thousands of words, and I need to create a new file based on certain parameters, and then sort them a certain way. 
Assuming the user imports the proper libraries when they test, what is wrong with my code? (There are 3 separate functions)

---

For the first, I must create a file with words containing certain letters, and sort them lexicographically, then put them into a new file list.txt.

```
def getSortedContain(s,ifile,ofile):
  toWrite = ""
  toWrites = ""
  for line in ifile:
      word = line[:-1]
      if s in word:
        toWrite += word + "\n"
  newList = []
  newList.append(toWrite)
  newList.sort()
  for h in newList:
      toWrites += h
  ofile.write(toWrites[:-1])
```

---

The second is similar, but must be sorted reverse lexicographically, if the string inputted is NOT in the word.

```
def getReverseSortedNotContain(s,ifile,ofile):
  toWrite = ""
  toWrites = ""
  for line in ifile:
      word = line[:-1]
      if s not in word:
         toWrite += word + "\n"
  newList = []
  newList.append(toWrite)
  newList.sort()
  newList.reverse()
  for h in newList:
      toWrites += h
  ofile.write(toWrites[:-1])
```

---

For the third, I must sort words that contain a certain amount of integers, and sort lexicographically by the last character in each word.

```
def getRhymeSortedCount(n, ifile, ofile):
  toWrite = ""
  for line in ifile:
      word = line[:-1] #gets rid of \n
      if len(word) == n:
          toWrite += word + "\n"
  reversetoWrite = toWrite[::-1]
  newList = []
  newList.append(toWrite)
  newList.sort()
  newList.reverse()
  for h in newList:
      toWrites += h
  reversetoWrite = toWrites[::-1]
  ofile.write(reversetoWrites[:-1])
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction for these? Right now they are not sorting as they're supposed to.

Comment: What is your specific problem? What do you expect the code to do *exactly*? What happens instead? (provide an example input, the desired output, and the actual output. Include the full traceback if any). See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of stuff that is unclear here so I'll try my best to clean this up.

You're concatenating strings together into one big string then appending that one big string into a list. You then tried to sort your 1-element list. This obviously will do nothing. Instead put all the strings into a list and then sort that list

IE: for your first example do the following:

```
def getSortedContain(s,ifile,ofile):
  words = [word for word in ifile if s in words]
  words.sort()
  ofile.write("\n".join(words))
```